# C++, overload * for matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having a great deal of trouble trying to overload the multiplication operator * for matrix multiplication. I've defined a matrix class

```
#ifndef MMATRIX_H
#define MMATRIX_H
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

// Class that represents a mathematical matrix
class MMatrix
{
public:
// constructors
MMatrix() : nRows(0), nCols(0) {}
MMatrix(int n, int m, double x = 0) : nRows(n), nCols(m), A(n * m, x)
{}

// set all matrix entries equal to a double
MMatrix &operator=(double x)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows * nCols; i++) 
        A[i] = x;
return *this;
}

// access element, indexed by (row, column) [rvalue]
double operator()(int i, int j) const
{
    return A[j + i * nCols];
}

// access element, indexed by (row, column) [lvalue]
double &operator()(int i, int j)
{
    return A[j + i * nCols];
}


// size of matrix
int Rows() const { return nRows; }
int Cols() const { return nCols; }

// operator overload for matrix * vector. Definition (prototype) of member class
MVector operator*(const MMatrix& A);

private:
unsigned int nRows, nCols;
std::vector<double> A;
};
#endif
```

And here is my attempted operator overload

```
inline MMatrix operator*(const MMatrix& A, const MMatrix& B)
{
MMatrix m(A), c(m.Rows(),m.Cols(),0.0);
for (int i=0; i<m.Rows(); i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<m.Cols(); j++)
    {
        for (int k=0; k<m.Cols(); k++)
        {
            c(i,j)+=m(i,k)*B(k,j);
        }
    }
}
return c;

}
```

I'm sure that there is nothing wrong with the actual multiplication of elements.

The error that I get is from my main .cpp file where I have tried to multiply two matrices together C=A*B; and I get this error,

error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'MMatrix' and 'MVector')

Comment: `MVector operator*(const MMatrix& A);` Whats MVector?

Comment: You declared a member `operator*` overload in the class, that returns an `MVector`, but then defined a global `operator*` overload that returns an `MMatrix`. Pick one of the return types, and choose whether you want to implement a class member, or a global function.

Comment: Okay, MVector is returning a vector for my matrix vector multiplication, that works fine though. I've now put MMatrix MMatrix::operator*(const MMatrix & A) in the class, though i'm unsure how i carry out the multiplication now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to overload `operator*`:

```
MMatrix MMatrix::operator*(MMatrix); //or const& or whatever you like
MMatrix operator*(MMatrix, MMatrix);
```

These are both valid, but different with slightly different semantics.

For your definition to match your declaration change the definition to:

```
MMatrix MMatrix::operator*(const MMatrix & A)
{
    //The two matrices to multiple are (*this) and A
    MMatrix c(Rows(),A.Cols(),0.0);
    for (int i=0; i < Rows(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < A.Cols(); j++)
        {
            for (int k=0; k < Cols(); k++)
            {
                c(i,j) += (*this)(i,k)*A(k,j);
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

As for the error you're seeing, it seems in your class you declared the operator to take a matrix and return a vector.  You probably meant to return a matrix instead.  The error is telling you that you can't assign a `MVector` to a `MMatrix`.

Comment: I've now put the prototype in the class as you suggested. The MVector returns for matrix vector multiplication. What I'm unsure about is how i multiply the matrices now. How does this work?

Comment: @wildboy Are you asking what the formula is for multiplying matrices?  There are many examples of code online you could follow for how to implement matrix multiplication.

Comment: You mention to change the definition from MMatrix operator*(const MMatrix& A, const MMatrix& B) to MMatrix MMatrix::operator*(const MMatrix & A). So i'm confused as to how I do the multiplication with only one matrix?

Comment: @wildboy You are defining a member function, in which case matrix _on the left side of the *_ is accessible via the `this` pointer.

Comment: How would I use the 'this' pointer in reference to particular elements of the matrix on the lhs?

Comment: @wildboy I filled in the body of the code for you, if you are confused about using `this` in member functions I suggest you look for a tutorial on it.  I don't have any to suggest for you offhand

Comment: Thanks :-) I think i understand that now.

Comment: @wildboy If this answers your question don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Sorry, I know this question is answered, but

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to define copy constructor and copy assignment:

```
MMatrix(const MMatrix& other);
MMatrix& operator=(const MMatrix& other);
```

Move constructor and assignment wouldn't heart either:

```
MMatrix(MMatrix&& other);
MMatrix& operator=(MMatrix&& other);
```

Same goes to your MVector.